# Issues with running HAL browser, Spring Data Rest and NGINX

Tags: spring, nginx, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2 to produce a Spring Data REST service that is hosted in a Docker container, deployed to a CoreOS cluster and routing is handled by NGINX.  Whew.  I'm trying to add in the HAL browser into this mix and I'm running into issues.

The URL advertised by NGINX is:

```
http://api.mycompany.com/api/postal-codes/v1/
```

NGINX maps that to a node in CoreOS running on a particular port, 100.200.300.400:12345:/, for example.

The links exported by HAL look like:

```
http://api.mycompany.com/postalCodes{?page,size,sort}
```

The "/api/postal-codes/v1" portion is not included by HAL.  I'm familiar with the spring.data.rest.base-path configuration and have tried that but to no avail. When I enable that option, the situation looks like:

To access the service, the path is now:

```
http://api.mycompany.com/api/postal-codes/v1/api/postal-codes/v1/
```

The links exported by HAL look like:

```
http://api.mycompany.com/api/postal-codes/v1/postalCodes{?page,size,sort}
```

So I'm chasing my tail.  The HAL links now include the /api/postal-codes/v1 but the service URL has moved as well.

Is there a way to get the advertised URL and the exported links to line up?

NGINX configuration rewrites requests to the upstream, stripping off the /api/postal-codes/v1 and replacing with /.  And default basePath for Spring Boot is /, which explains why HAL has the links that it does, just not ones that work.

Comment: One idea I had would be to set baseUri in RepositoryRestConfiguration, http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html, but I don't see a way to set baseUri.

Comment: Seems like base-uri was deprecated in Spring Boot 1.2.3.